# How to prevent deselect annotation on MKMapView in SwiftUI when app goes in to background

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, mapkit, mapkitannotation

Inside my SwiftUI view, I using MKMapView wrapped through the UIViewRepresentable protocol. On the map I have an annotation, when I select it and minimize the application into background, then the annotation automatically becomes unselected again. This behavior is different if using UIKit, where the annotation does not become unselected in the same case. Is it possible to achieve the same behavior using SwiftUI?

Here is my code for SwiftUI map

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    private var mapView = MKMapView()
    
    let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.785091, longitude: -73.968285)
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) -> MKMapView {
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        mapView.userTrackingMode = .follow
        
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinates, latitudinalMeters: 1000, longitudinalMeters: 1000)
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
        
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<MapView>) {
        addAnnotations()
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapView.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
    private func addAnnotations() {
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.coordinate = coordinates
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        
    }
}

extension MapView {
    
    final class Coordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        let parent: MapView
        
        init(_ parent: MapView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
            debugPrint("Select annotation")
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
            debugPrint("Deselect annotation")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the UIViewRepresantable method calls each time when app back to the foreground(Why?) That means that annotation will be removed and add again each time this happens. So basically all you need to do it's make sure the annotation that is you trying to add to the map is not already presented there. If the new annotations don't contain some annotation that is already presented then you have to remove it.

I handled it like this:

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<SCMapView>) {
        createAnnotations(uiView)
}
    
private func createAnnotations(_ view: MKMapView) {
    let oldAnnotations = view.annotations
    var newAnnotations: [PostAnnotation] = viewStore.annotations
        
    if !oldAnnotations.isEmpty {
        for annotation in oldAnnotations {
            if let postAnnotation = annotation as? PostAnnotation {
                if !newAnnotations.contains(where: { $0.post.id == postAnnotation.post.id }) {
                     view.removeAnnotation(postAnnotation)
                } else {
                     newAnnotations.removeAll(where: { $0.post.id == postAnnotation.post.id })
                }
             }
         }
     }
        
    if !newAnnotations.isEmpty {
        view.addAnnotations(newAnnotations)
    }
 }
```